# Using MSVC preprocessor 'charizing' operator in Clang

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, c-preprocessor

I've got the following code that someone working on MSVC has given to me:

```
#define MAP1(x, y) map[#x] = #@y;
```

I'm on Xcode, using Clang, and from various google searches I've found that this is known as a 'charizing operator', and is specific to MSVC's preprocessor. Is there a way of emulating the functionality of this operator while using Clang? I've tried removing the `@` but got the following error message:

```
Assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'const char[2]'
```

Would an explicit cast to 'int' work or is the charizing operator doing something different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stringizing operator (standard C++) converts `a` into `"a"`, so the charizing operator sounds like it turns `a` into `'a'`. You can, in the simple cases, get `'a'` from `"a"` by taking the first character.

```
#define MAP1(x, y) map[#x] = static_cast<const char(&)[2]>(#y)[0];
```

The `static_cast` to `const char(&)[2]` ensures you get a compile-time error if you don't get a string of length 1, which is two characters if you count the trailing `'\0'`. A plain `#y[0]` would silently take the first character, regardless of the string's length.

Comment: Thanks - for keeping the behaviour consistent with that of MSVC, do you know if MSVC's charizing operator would throw an error if given a string longer than one character?

Comment: @benwad I don't know, but if it doesn't, you'd probably get (for example) `'ab'`, which is very different from `"ab"[0]`, and that would make it very complicated to get the exact same behaviour as VC's `#@`.

Comment: For the record, MSVC *will* charize sequences of more than one character. Note that character constants with more than one character are allowed in C and C++ but have an implementation-defined value, and the type `int`, not `char` (in both languages).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like #y[0]? Basically, "stringify y and take the first char" :-)

Other than that, since from the looks of it the generated statements are executed at runtime anyway, you can just stringify y, pass it to a function and have that function return the right thing.